# Clickonce Deployment - How to do partial update

Tags: clickonce, partial

Here is my problem which I thought was very simple but after spending few hours I just could not get a fix.

I have a .NET application and have deployed it to a network share using Clickonce publish option Visual Studio 2010.

On the client computer the application is installed succesfully.

Now I had to change a file in my application. I replace the file in the "Application Files" folder, updated the app.exe.maifest file using Mage UI. (Verified the hash got changed for the modified file).

Now updated the .application file so that the hash in it is also recreated because of the change in the app.exe.manifest file.

But when I lauch the application on the client, its not recognizing the update.

Im at loss to understand why is the app not updating.

Any ideas/pointers help is really appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

To create an update, you need to increment the version number and publish the new version to the same folder as the original deployment.

Comment: How can you do this when using msbuild and the project to publish? Based on reading the available targets I am having a hard time seeing how I can separate the dll version from the path where the assemblies are published.

Comment: Thank Robin, you have already answered my question elsewhere.

First publish like you normally would. Then update the files which have changed in the existing directory and make sure the manifest/vsto is update/pointing to the right path. Resign the manifest/vsto files.

As long as the hash and last modified are the same I should be good. This is what I have groked from your other answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3223673/best-way-for-update-application